# SQL query to get the details

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

We have a database with machine details such as ID, Hostname, IP Address, OS, etc...

```
ID  IP Address      Hostname     Protocol    NetMask
1   10.216.16.47    Test123         DNS     255.255.255.0
1   10.216.16.48    Test123         DNS     255.255.255.0
54  10.216.68.85    Test73711340    DNS     255.255.255.0
71  10.216.63.101   Test737101230   DNS     255.255.255.0
94  10.216.34.153   Test10000182    DNS     255.255.255.0
```

I need to write a query which will find a machine with two IP addresses and give the output with a separate column for each IP.

Expected output:

```
ID  IP Address     IP Address 2     Hostname      Protocol      NetMask
1   10.216.16.47   10.216.16.48    Test123         DNS      255.255.255.0
54  10.216.68.85    Null           Test73711340    DNS      255.255.255.0
71  10.216.63.101   Null           Test737101230   DNS      255.255.255.0
94  10.216.34.153   Null           Test10000182    DNS      255.255.255.0
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this result, you'll first need to use a windowing function like `row_number()` to assign a distinct value for each row in the `ID` - meaning that any multiple rows of `ID` you'll create a unique sequence within that ID.

I'd suggest using row_number similar to:

```
select id,
 IPAddress,
  Hostname,
  Protocol,
  NetMask,
  col = 'IPAddress'+
          cast(row_number() over(partition by id order by IPAddress) as varchar(1))
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2769a/4). This query creates a new computed column that has the sequence and then concatenates the term 'IPAddress' to the front of it, you'll notice that `ID=1` has two values `IPAddress1` and `IPAddress2` - these new values will be used as the new columns.

```
| ID |     IPADDRESS |      HOSTNAME | PROTOCOL |       NETMASK |        COL |
|----|---------------|---------------|----------|---------------|------------|
|  1 |  10.216.16.47 |       Test123 |      DNS | 255.255.255.0 | IPAddress1 |
|  1 |  10.216.16.48 |       Test123 |      DNS | 255.255.255.0 | IPAddress2 |
```

Then if you want to convert this to columns, you can use the PIVOT function:

```
select id,
  IPAddress1,
  IPAddress2,
  Hostname,
  Protocol,
  NetMask
from
(
  select id,
    IPAddress,
    Hostname,
    Protocol,
    NetMask,
    col = 'IPAddress'+
            cast(row_number() over(partition by id order by IPAddress) as varchar(1))
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(IPAddress)
  for col in (IPAddress1, IPAddress2)
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2769a/3).

Or you could also get the result using an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select id,
  IPAddress1 = max(case when rn = 1 then IPAddress end),
  IPAddress2 = max(case when rn = 2 then IPAddress end),
  Hostname,
  Protocol,
  Netmask
from
(
  select id,
    IPAddress,
    Hostname,
    Protocol,
    NetMask,
    rn = row_number() over(partition by id order by IPAddress)
  from yourtable
) d
group by id, hostname, protocol, netmask;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2769a/5). Both the pivot and the case version will give a result of:

```
| ID |    IPADDRESS1 |   IPADDRESS2 |      HOSTNAME | PROTOCOL |       NETMASK |
|----|---------------|--------------|---------------|----------|---------------|
|  1 |  10.216.16.47 | 10.216.16.48 |       Test123 |      DNS | 255.255.255.0 |
| 54 |  10.216.68.85 |       (null) |  Test73711340 |      DNS | 255.255.255.0 |
| 71 | 10.216.63.101 |       (null) | Test737101230 |      DNS | 255.255.255.0 |
| 94 | 10.216.34.153 |       (null) |  Test10000182 |      DNS | 255.255.255.0 |
```